# error with package bookmark - fails to load "rerunfilecheck.sty"

Tags: bookmarks, compilation-error

I run this code

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\begin{document}
    Test
\end{document}
```

And it results in the error

```
! LaTeX Error: File `rerunfilecheck.sty' not found.
```

in `hluatex.def`

Compiled with latest Texlive on windows.

Comment: install the rerunfilecheck package.

Comment: Obvious. But the Textlive Manager does not know the package.

Comment: Today it was shown in the list of not installed packages and after the installation the error is not present anymore.